# ListView items are overlapped

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, listviewitem

Items listView are overlapped after delete items. Why? For example before and after delete first item:

[image]

I am deleting elements using method:

```
public void updateData(List<ParseObject> data) {
    mGroupList.clear();
    mGroupList.addAll(data);
    notifyDataSetChanged();
}
```

listView:

```
<ListView
    android:id="@android:id/list"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:divider="@null"/>
```

getView in adapter:

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder viewHolder;

    if (convertView == null) {
        viewHolder = new ViewHolder();
        convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
        viewHolder.mCardViewNative = (CardViewNative) convertView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);
        convertView.setTag(viewHolder);
    } else {
        viewHolder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    } 

    //code

    viewHolder.mCardViewNative.setCard(card);

    return convertView;
}
```

card_item.xml:

```
<it.gmariotti.cardslib.library.view.CardViewNative
android:background="@drawable/header_dark"
android:id="@+id/card_view"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```

**UPDATE**

If don't use ViewHolder and inflate view everytime, there is no overlap. But inflate view everytime is not good.

```
@Override
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
    CardViewNative cardViewNative = (CardViewNative) convertView.findViewById(R.id.card_view);

    //code

    cardViewNative.setCard(card);

    return convertView;
}
```

Comment: can you share your code?

Comment: are you calling notifyDataSetChanged() after Delete and Add?

Comment: @MeenalSharma [my code on github](https://github.com/lborlandl/Debts/blob/master/app/src/main/java/ua/ck/geekhub/ivanov/debts/adapters/GroupAdapter.java)

Comment: @Manikanta, yes, code in Adapter:
        mGroupList.clear();
        mGroupList.addAll(data);
        notifyDataSetChanged();

Comment: try final ParseObject group = mGroupList.get(position); in place of this final ParseObject group = getGroup(position);

Comment: @MeenalSharma, unfortunately it does not work

Comment: @MaxIvanov do you have your ListView in fragment? Maybe some fragments are added on top of each other, not the list items.

Comment: @deville I am use fragment, but the problem is not in it. I think, problem in the adapter, look to my update. Also, I replace fragment, no add.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try

```
convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_item, null);
```

Instead of

```
convertView = mLayoutInflater.inflate(R.layout.card_item, parent, false);
```

It works for me, using ViewHolder as static class

Comment: I made ViewHolder static. But It not working for me anyway, unfortunately.

Comment: Not working for me either. In my case few items showing overlapped even on first load.